# Completeness of Besov spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, besov-space

**Problem:** Let us recall that:
$$\dot{B}^{-\sigma}_{\infty,\infty}=\{u \in S'(\mathbb{R}^d): \|u\|_{\dot{B}^{-\sigma}_{\infty,\infty}} < \infty\}$$
where
$$\|u\|_{\dot{B}^{-\sigma}_{\infty,\infty}}=\sup\limits_{A>0}\{A^{d-\sigma}\|  \theta(A\cdot)* u\|_{L^{\infty}}\}$$
and $S'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the set of tempered distributions.
I want to understand two things:

- why $\dot{B}^{-\sigma}_{\infty,\infty}$ is complete (i.e. a Banach space)
- why if I choose another $\theta'$ I obtain an equivalent norm over $\dot{B}^{-\sigma}_{\infty,\infty}$.

**Attempt.** I tried exploiting the Fourier transorm of a tempered distribution:
$$\theta(A\cdot)* u= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}(\theta(A\cdot)* u)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\bigg(A^{-d}\mathcal{F}\Big(\theta\Big(\frac{\cdot}{A}\Big)\Big) \mathcal{F}(u)\bigg)$$
but I cannot go on. Any help or reference will be appreciate. Please notice that I would like a **self-contained proof** instead one for general Besov spaces as $\dot{B}^{\sigma}_{p,q}$.

*Edit*: we assume $\mathcal{F}(\theta)$ is such that $\mathcal{F}(\theta) \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $0 \leq \mathcal{F}(\theta) \leq 1$ and $\mathcal{F}(\theta)=1$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $\theta$?

Comment: @Jose27 I edited the quesiton

Comment: I posted an answer about the completeness of this space in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4127104/homogeneous-besov-space-dot-b-sigma-mathbb-rd-is-a-banach-space

Answer (score 1):

The proofs of these facts can be found in Remark 2.17 and Theorem 2.25 in the book *Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations* by Hajer Bahouri, Jean-Yves Chemin and Raphaël Danchin.

Comment: As I said in the question I would like a self-contained proof, but I will check and I will say if does fit for me.